# Поиск поста с несколькими категориями

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Подскажите пожалуйста. у меня допустим для каждого поста в базе хранятся хэши с массивами

```
{:genre => ["сказка", "история", "военный"]}
{:genre => ["роман", "история"]}
{:genre => ["фантастика", "военный"]}
```

и есть запрос вывести все посты где есть жанр военный.

Скажем так, посты с книгами где есть несколько категорий. А запрос я делаю из списка категорий. как мне вывести все посты где есть жанр допустим военный. Я делаю так, но это не работает:

```
    class BooksController < ApplicationController
        def index         
            if params[:category].blank?
               @books = Book.all.page(params[:page]).per(20)
            else 
#----------------------------------------------------
               @category = Category.find_by(genre: params[:category]).genre            
               @books = Book.where(:genre => [@category]).page(params[:page]).per(20)
#----------------------------------------------------
           end
        end 
     end



class Book < ApplicationRecord
    serialize :genre, Array
    belongs_to :category, required: false
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :books
end
```

И сама таблица:

```
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "genre"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"    
    t.string "genre"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "autрor"  
    t.string "year"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "image_link"
    t.integer "category_id"
end
```

Как можно организовать такой поиск?

Comment: Я запуталась в ваших постах, категориях и книгах. Будет здорово, если к вопросу вы добавите структуру моделей. ИМХО, вам станет гораздо легче жить, если вы жанры будете хранить не массивом, а свяжете с нужной вам моделью через has_many

Comment: Я создавал колонку индексов категорий в посте, но всё равно упираюсь в то, что пост будет хранить массив этих индексов.

Comment: А зачем у вас книга принадлежит к категории (которая, похоже и является жанром) и при этом ещё и хранит в себе список жанров? Что мешает сделать `Category has_and_belongs_to_many :books` и наоборот? Ну или `has_many_through`, не люблю я HABTM

Comment: "посты с книгами где есть несколько категорий" -- а что у вас вообще такое "посты"?

Comment: @chelosobaka, я обновила ответ

Answer (score 0):

Не очень хватает данных для полноценного ответа, но я попробую. Вообще запрос должен выглядеть чем-то вроде

```
Model.where("column_name->'genre' ? :genre", genre: @category)
```

Оператор `?` используется для проверки - содержится ли строка справа от него в json'е слева от него. 
Ну и ваш столбец должен быть индексирован для поиска, он же jsonb?

UPDATE:

С моделями и схемой стало гораздо понятнее. Честное слово, это очень плохая идея - искать по serialized полю. Неудобно и неэффективно. Насколько я понимаю, самым адекватным тут будет:

```
Book.where("genre ILIKE ?", "% #{ @category }\n%")
```

Serialized поля в базе хранятся в виде `1\n 2\n 3\n` для `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, так что не забудьте пробел перед @category и \n после неё.

Если уж вам по какой-то причине нужно хранить эти значения в массиве, и у вас постгрес, воспользуйтесь опцией `array: true` для столбца genre, тогда вы сможете использовать оператор @> для работы с массивом.

Но вообще попробуйте всё-таки объяснить, чего вы хотите добиться от вашей структуры данных, и внесите ясность в именования (почему Book вы называете постом, и как соотносятся жанр и категория), и тогда скорее всего получится помочь.

Comment: Э-э-э, судя по моделям и схеме, нет, не `jsonb`. Но жанр тут совершенно несущественен, поиск требуется по категориям, насколько я понимаю.

Comment: @D-side, модели и схема в вопросе появились уже после моего ответа. Вроде как, жанр и категория - это одно и то же. Я обновила ответ

Comment: По этой причине я стараюсь не отвечать на вопросы, в которых слишком много свободных переменных: слишком высок риск потратить усилия и написать полезный материал, который придётся выкинуть из-за нерелевантности к вопросу :\

Comment: @D-side, я это понимаю, но очень хорошо помню, как совсем недавно мне тоже иногда было сложно даже вопрос нормально задать из-за нехватки знаний. Поэтому иногда всё-таки пытаюсь отвечать почти наугад :)

Comment: Постом я называл Книгу, думал так будет более понятно. Каждая книга имеет несколько жанров. А категории - это поиск по жанрам. Возможно даже моя идея поиска была не совсем верная, что завело в тупик. Прислушаюсь наверное к совету организовать связь HABTM....